# python: scrape site with randomized attributes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

**Full disclosure**: I'm brand new to web scraping, and my experience with html is very limited. Please tell me if I am doing something wrong, or if you need more info.

**Private content**: MY_PASSWORD, MY_USERNAME, MY_SCHOOL, SITE2

**My goal**: Scrape a school webpage (`https://SITE2.MY_SCHOOL.edu/Main_Page.Asp?Page=Select_Subject`) that I have access to with my student account.

**Website info**: When I enter `https://SITE2.MY_SCHOOL.edu/` on a browser, I get redirected to `https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/?App=J4200` to login to my school account.

After logging in, I get redirected back to `https://SITE2.MY_SCHOOL.edu/Main_Page.Asp?Page=Select_Subject` (the page I want to scrape)

**Problem**: On refresh of `https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/?App=J4200`, the name attribute of input id/type 'password' is randomized, and the value attribute of input name 'EncryptedStamp' is randomized. I am able to get all of this information from the loaded page, as shown below. when I call `session.post('https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/?App=J4200', data=form)`

```py
import requests, lxml.html

s = requests.session()
login = s.get("https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/")

login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')

  # The input type 'password' has a name tag that changes on refresh
  # See the example form below
password_input = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="password"]')

password_nametag = password_input[0].name
jse_id = s.cookies['JSESSIONID']

  # Create dict used as 'data' argument of POST request
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
form['AlternateID'] = 'MY_USERNAME'    # AlternateID is name tag for username
form[password_nametag] = 'MY_PASSWORD'
form['JSESSIONID'] = jse_id
```

Example form:

```
{'AlternateID': 'MY_USERNAME',
 'App': 'MY_SCHOOLNet',
 'EncryptedStamp': 'ZYWSNQLPJKMH',
 'JSESSIONID': 'EFC8B3319A63332484DFE8F90E4E0272',
 'MXVQY': 'MY_PASSWORD'}
```

Response:

```
response = s.post('https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/?App=J4200', data=form)
         # s.get will return the same results
print(response.url)
  'https://login.MY_SCHOOL.edu/'
  # I think this should be https://SITE2.MY_SCHOOL.edu/Main_Page.Asp?Page=Select_Subject
```

Rerun all form lines to update form:

```
{'AlternateID': 'MY_USERNAME',
'App': 'MY_SCHOOLNet',
'EncryptedStamp':'ZYWSNQLPJKMH',
'JSESSIONID':'EFC8B3319A63332484DFE8F90E4E0272',
'RYCSX': 'MY_PASSWORD'}
```

**What I think the solution is**: Update the page without refreshing the page, to prevent the two attributes from changing. I have no idea how though. Googling said to use JQuery, but that is a steep learning curve for results that I may not even get.

Thanks for reading, and I look forward to any suggestions.

Comment: I solved my problem with a python library called RoboBrowser